# How do we send custom payload with a Dialogflow bot in the Slack way?

Tags: dialogflow-es, slack

I wanted to try a very simple custom payload to slack:

```
{
    "text": "in custom payload"
}
```

However, when I send the related catchphrase Dialogflow returns `Not available`:

[image]

So how do we send custom payload with a Dialogflow bot in the Slack way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send a simple text message using the following custom payload.

```
{
  "slack": {
    "text": "Testing custom payloads",
    "attachments": []
  }
}
```

Because you are using a custom payload Dialogflow will not be able to [display](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/intents-rich-messages#custom-payload) the response.

[image]
If you want to test the response you should connect it as a slack [integration](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/slack#link_slack_to_dialogflow) to your bot.

Comment: Thanks, I can now test it in Slack properly. Do you know how I can deploy/launch it?

Comment: More info on adding a bot to your workspace can be found in the Slack docs, it walks you through all the steps https://api.slack.com/bot-users#installing-bot. Please accept answers that help you as the answer to your question, this helps others in showing this solved your issue.